# Not able to connect Android Wear Emulator with Device

Tags: android, wear-os

I am not able to connect Android Wear Emulator with my device.I have HTC One device which has 4.4 (KitKat OS).

I follow below link :

[Setting up Android Wear](http://developer.android.com/wear/preview/start.html)

But, when I execute the line ***adb -d forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601*** through command prompt,nothing happens.Android Wear emulator does not show device connected.

**Note** : I am able to launch the ***Android Wear Preview app*** successfully in my device and Notifications settings is also enabled.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: some times emulator ram grater than 778 fail depending on the system load.

Comment: But in docs, they have mentioned that we dont need to change that and keep it as it is by default.

Comment: yes it is, But there is some same problem happen to me and i fixed like this, Try this one

Comment: So, What value should I enter for Android Wear Emulator to work?

Comment: try some value smaller than 778.

Comment: Does not work bro :( I tried with 512. My question is do we need to use "same value 5601 ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50104/discussion-between-sid-and-sreekanthss)

Comment: Make sure you see both your device and the emulator when you type "adb devices". If you see just one you'll have to do the usual adb dance of plugging devices in, unplugging them, adb kill-server, try again, etc.. Maybe sure the app is running on your phone, added as a notification listener, and your phone has ADB debugging enabled. Have both phone and watch ready to go and run the command.

Answer (score 23):

@Lance Nanek basically helped me solved this problem. In case you had the similar problem, these steps might be helpful.

1. run 'adb devices' , you should see two devices, one is your
   emulator, the other is your device with Android Wear Preview app
   installed.
2. you might see your emulator offline, if so, kill the emulator. From avd, start it, carefully uncheck 'launch from snapshot' - this
   is contrast to Android Wear Get started instruction: "Start the AVD
   again, but select Launch from snapshot and deselect Save to
   snapshot."
3. run 'adb devices' again, make sure you do see two
   devices online
4. run command 'adb -d forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601'
5. from the android wear preview app, tape connect, you should be ready
   to go.

Comment: how can you have two devices and yet run the adb -d switch, -d is for only one device connected use the -s along with the device id shown in devices.

Answer (score 21):

On the newly updated Android Wear app (Aug 2014) there is a settings button top right when asked to choose a device connected via bluetooth.  Pressing this button will connect to an emulator instead.

Comment: it worked for me. I think it should be the right answer from Aug 2014 and beyond.

Answer (score 3):

1. Enable adb debugging in the developer options on your watch.
2. Enable bluetooth debugging in the developer options on your watch.
3. Enable bluetooth debugging in the wear app on your phone. run in terminal:
4. adb forward tcp:4444 localabstract:/adb-hub; adb connect localhost:4444

[See this training](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/bt-debugging.html).

I think I also had luck with using the cradle plugged directly into the computer, but unable to confirm that now.

Answer (score 1):

Android Wear using Genymotion
For people who does not have a phone with Android 4.3 or above, we can not try the Android Wear Preview. :'(
And here is a way you can try, use Genymotion Nexus 4 or any other emulator with Android 4.3 or Android 4.4 and it works!

Setup a Nexus 4 with Android 4.3 in Genymotion.
Start both the Nexus 4 and Android Wear emulator.
You should first install Google Play Services on the Nexus 4:
Download the zip file
Drag it into the Nexus 4
Reboot the device, and now you are able to install "Android Wear Preview" on Play Store
Open Terminal, use adb tools:
adb devices
you shoud see 2 devices,
adb -s [device name of Nexus 4] forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601
Done!

Answer (score 1):

The trouble I was having, was that the pre-selected API level was set incorrectly. It should be set to the following values:

[image: Virtual device settings for Android Wear]

Using Host GPU is optional.

Answer (score 1):

Stuck with the same a while ago. It appeared that Google updated their [Android Wear](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.wearable.app) app. After installing the new version I was able to connect successfully to wear through its interface (as long as I used device with **android 4.3+** and **adb -d forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601** command)

Answer (score 1):

After some hours trying to find the solution... I've found it!

In my case, the problem was that I have two different SDKs (one from Eclipse and the other from Android Studio), so I was trying to execute the ADB commands in the wrong one.

So it is important that you check the path you are using in your IDE and execute the commands on the same.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting suck on "Connecting to Emulator", but I fixed it by using an Android Wear ARM virtual device instead of an x86 one.

Answer (score 0):

Run the *adb -d forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601* command in super user mode

Comment: Never use superuser for anything from the command line if there is a way to do otherwise.

Comment: Don't know why folks here love downvote collaborative people. Ironically, this twice downvoted answer helped me a lot for now! Thanks mate!