# Android Wear Preview not connecting to Wear Emulator

Tags: android, adb, wear-os

I am trying to setup my development environment for Google Wear and have followed Google's [instructions](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html) but as soon as I setup the port forwarding (`adb -d forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601`) I am getting an error on the device;

`Connection closed, waiting before trying again`

I have the emulator running on the PC and Android device is a Nexus 4, 4.4.4.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not able to connect Android Wear Emulator with Device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524760/not-able-to-connect-android-wear-emulator-with-device)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you've updated everything, and have the new emulator, you might need Android Wear (not Android Wear Preview). Follow these steps: http://developer.android.com/preview/google-play-services-wear.html

You may have done this recently, but now that Google Play Services 5.0, and Android Wear is out (unofficially) it's worth trying again to get the latest updates.

**OR**, you may just need to click that emulator button in the screenshot, to let the app know you're connecting to an emulator.

Answer (score 5):

One issue I found when attempting to do this 2 weeks ago, is that despite the documentation saying to save the image to a snapshot, the emulator will not connect when launched from a snapshot. Launch the emulator and uncheck the box for "launch from snapshot."

Once the emulator is running, run

```
adb devices
```

and ensure the watch emulator is showing and has "device" next to it.  If it does, then you can run

```
adb -d forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601
```

Now try connecting the preview app.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble I was having, was that the pre-selected API level was set incorrectly. It should be set to the following values:

[image: Virtual device settings for Android Wear]

Using Host GPU is optional.

Answer (score 0):

Stuck with the same a while ago. It appeared that Google updated their [Android Wear](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.wearable.app) app - the one on the screenshot in the question is out-of-dated version. After installing new version everything worked for me (as long as I used device  with **android 4.3+** and **adb -d forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601** command to connect to wear emulator)