# Genymotion and Android Wear emulator try to connect all the time

Tags: android, android-emulator, wear-os, genymotion

I have a problem pairing Genymotion and Android Wear emulator. I followed [this](http://joelifernandes.com/android/working-genymotion-android-wear/) tutorial:

1. Install Android Wear emulator (api 22) and Genymotion (api 19).
2. Install **Android Wear** and **Android Wear Preview** on Genymotion.
3. `adb -s [dev name] forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601`
4. Open **Android Wear Preview** and try to connect, but the application is disconnecting all the time and trying again, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454185/android-wear-preview-not-connecting-to-wear-emulator) post.
5. Open another instance of **Android Wear**, the same happens.
6. Download the new Genymotion emulator api 22, the same happens.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've spent like 3 hours trying to solve this issue and finally I managed to connect the Android Wear emulator with a Genymotion Google Nexus 4, 5.0.0 API 21 using *Android Wear*, as suggested in the post you're referring, though I had to download the apk on my computer from [here](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/android-wear/android-wear-1-1-1-2016316-android-apk-download/) and then drag and drop on the emulator, because Google Services says any Genymotion emulator to be not compatible with *Android Wear* when trying to install it.

So in the end it's working correctly, but I don't know the reason of Android Wear Preview's malfunctionning, Aaron D. Sorry.