# Pairing android wear emulator with handheld device

Tags: android, wear-os

How to pair android wear emulator and hand held device ?

Followed the instructions given in the below site
[https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siC5d.png)

But some how not able to succeed in pairing android wear emulator with handheld device.
Found some of the problems listed below

1. Android wear emulator showing always disconnected in home screen
2. In handheld device always displays "connecting.." as connection status if android wear companion app got opens up

Please verify images below for details

[image: android wear emulator]

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Follow the link in comments section for solution

Comment: Check out the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524760/not-able-to-connect-android-wear-emulator-with-device

Comment: Yes got the solution thanks for the link.I missed enabling of notification settings before.